# Google Analytics Event Tracking Mailto Links

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Firstly, not being a developer, this may seem basic, but here it goes..

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to install event tracking code for Google Analytics (A-Sync ga.js)

```
<a href="mailto:mail@mail.com" onClick=""_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','send', 'event', 'email mailto', 'clicked', 'mail@mail.com');">email@email.com</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax errors and some extraneous parameters in your onclick code. Assuming you are using classic GA (via the 'ga' obj) it should be

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'email mailto', 'clicked', 'mail@mail.com']);"
```

So you had double quotes containing nothing, extra 'send' and 'event' parameters, and a missing closing square bracket.

More documentation can be found here for the event tracker: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide